# Is it possible to have both Desktop Cube and Unity?

Tags: unity, compiz, cube

I recently learned that few things in Compiz conflicts with Unity, hence Unity crashes when CCSM is installed. Is it possible by anyway, to have both? (I badly love both Unity Launcher and Desktop Cube)

Comment: Info: I use Ubu 11.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:
http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/howto-get-the-compiz-desktop-cube-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-and-unity/